# No wifi capabilities on Toshiba Satellite A665

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, software-installation

I recently got a Satellite A665 from a buddy who was looking to get rid of his stuff. The first thing I did was try to put on Ubuntu 14.04 which went just fine as it has for me in the past. But I couldn't get wifi to work on it. It says a hardware switch was disabling it but I already hit FN+F8 to unblock it that way to no avail. I then went to terminal and typed "rfkill unblock all" but nothing changed. I then put "iwconfig" into terminal and saw I had a wlan0 interface but it didn't work. I saw an eth0, l0, and wmx0 but it said "no wireless extensions". I looked online and saw that I needed a few drivers to support my wifi card but from there in totally confused on what to do. The lshw -c netwrok output: `*-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 1c:75:08:6f:88:17
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 5f
       serial: 00:23:15:9e:72:98
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-30-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:43 memory:d4600000-d4601fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wmx0
       serial: 64:d4:da:1a:5b:26
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: driver=i2400m_usb firmware=i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf link=no`
The lsmod output: 
`Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69509  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
bluetooth             446409  10 bnep,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47548  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    72791  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68937  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
uvcvideo               81073  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
i2400m_usb             36540  0 
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
i2400m                107914  1 i2400m_usb
wimax                  34705  1 i2400m
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_hda_intel          30469  3 
snd_hda_controller     31056  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139682  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               104112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
arc4                   12608  2 
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
iwldvm                232283  0 
snd_seq                63074  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
intel_powerclamp       18823  0 
mac80211              652718  1 iwldvm
coretemp               13441  0 
kvm_intel             143590  0 
kvm                   452043  1 kvm_intel
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29562  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
joydev                 17393  0 
serio_raw              13483  0 
intel_ips              18484  0 
iwlwifi               179412  1 iwldvm
jmb38x_ms              18736  0 
i915                  905798  8 
memstick               16966  1 jmb38x_ms
cfg80211              494330  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
drm_kms_helper         61574  1 i915
snd                    79468  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
drm                   311018  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 19696  0 
toshiba_acpi           28272  0 
mei                    87875  1 mei_me
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
lpc_ich                21093  0 
shpchp                 37047  0 
soundcore              15047  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
sparse_keymap          13948  1 toshiba_acpi
wmi                    19193  1 toshiba_acpi
toshiba_bluetooth      12867  0 
ene_ir                 18449  0 
rc_core                28718  1 ene_ir
video                  20128  1 i915
mac_hid                13227  0 
parport_pc             32741  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
psmouse               106561  0 
ahci                   34062  2 
libahci                32424  1 ahci
r8169                  71694  0 
sdhci_pci              23301  0 
sdhci                  43685  1 sdhci_pci
mii                    13934  1 r8169`

Comment: would be nice if you added output of  `sudo lsmod` and `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: I added it to my original post. I am a bit new here and couldn't figure out how to post outputs in a comment.

Comment: What is the result of `rfkill list all`

Answer (score 0):

On Toshiba A665, The hardware touch button (on top of the keyboard) to enable/disable the wireless adapter actually works. So may be you need just to press it to enable wireless.

Comment: I tried multiple times and nothing. Prior to ubuntu I tried to install arche and that went fine with wifi connection. Then I tried debian and it said I was missing iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode, iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode, rtl_nic/rtl81868e-2.fw drivers. So I downloaded those in a deb file and clicked the open with Ubuntu Software Center. Then that install failed. Now I'm here.

Comment: There is a button between the speakers with a wifi icon on it that will enable wifi when it is hard blocked.  Try it when the Toshiba splash screen is on the monitor when booting if it doesn't work when Ubuntu is running

Answer (score 0):

[image: Toshiba A665]

If this is identical to yours, the second button from the power button on the right(between F8 and display) should remove a hard block in rfkill on the wifi.  I have a Toshiba laptop with a similar setup.  The FN combo can only soft block the wifi